# Combining lots of photo folders

Tags: photos, file

I have lots of photo folders, including some with duplicates. I want to end up with a master set which contains everything, with no duplicates.

I was wondering what would be the best way to do this? I don’t mind paying for software to do it. Current thinking is I could make a new Apple Photos library, import everything, and then export it. I’m hoping that will help combine and remove duplicates but I imagine there would be a better way.

Comment: Apple photos runs on iPad and iPhone and macOS. Are you in possession of all three  platforms for this task? Solving this on macOS is very easy with https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/

Comment: I've used [Gemini 2](https://macpaw.com/gemini) for this kind of task.